# How to fetch the required content from a shell command output that is stored in a Register in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to find a way to store the content of the NSLOOKUP command that i run in Ansible to find a CNAME associated with an application. The CNAME changes accordingly with application to application.

I performed *nslookup* in shell and registered the output.

```
- name: Shell Command to perform NSLOOKUP 
  shell: nslookup abc.xyz.com                                        
  register: result                                 
- debug: var=result
```

The Output of NSLOOKUP :

```
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Server:\t\t10.10.10.10", 
        "Address:\t10.10.10.11#53", 
        "", 
        "abc.xyz.com\tcanonical name = abc.web.xyz.com.", 
        "Name:\tabc.web.xyz.com", 
        "Address: 10.210.120.111"
    ]
```

Basically i need to fetch the output of the Value of Name , this value change dynamically from application to application . So i can't use stdout_lines[5] this won't work for each scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task below reports the *value*(s) of *Name*(s)

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.split('\t').1 }}"
  loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
  when: item is match('^Name:*')
```

and the next task creates a list of the *Name*(s') *value*(s)

```
- set_fact:
    names: "{{ names|default([]) + [ item.split('\t').1 ] }}"
  loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
  when: item is match('^Name:*')
- debug:
    var: names
```

Preferred option should be Ansible native [dig – query DNS using the dnspython library](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dig.html).